Problems with height and width of mat-dialog-actions container
I'm running into some problems when designing a dialogue. I'm using the Angular Material components and have two challenges:
Height of the mat-dialog-actions container: The mat-dialog-actions container has a height that is too low, which results in the distance between mat-dialog-actions and mat-dialog-content being too small. This results in an unwanted overlap as shown in the green line in the attached image.
Alignment of the input elements: The input elements within the dialog are not flush with the buttons in the mat-dialog-actions container. The input fields appear to be slightly shifted upwards, resulting in an unclear display, as can be seen in the blue line in the image.
Is there a recommended course of action to resolve these issues? I would appreciate any help or advice.

task-view.html
<div mat-dialog-title class="title-container">
  <h2>Add Task</h2>
  @if (fromPopup) {
    <button mat-icon-button mat-dialog-close color="primary" aria-label="close dialog">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
  }
</div>

<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography content-container" [formGroup]="taskForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="title" type="text" placeholder="Enter a title">
    <mat-icon color="primary" matSuffix>subject</mat-icon>
    @if (taskForm.get('title')?.touched) {
      <mat-error>
        @switch (true) {
          @case (taskForm.get('title')?.hasError('required')) {
            Title is required
          }
        }
      </mat-error>
    }
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!taskForm.valid">Create Task</button>
  <button mat-raised-button type="button" color="warn" (click)="resetForm()">Clear</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>

Dialog
public addTaskDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(TaskViewComponent, {
      panelClass: [""],
      data: { fromPopup: true },
    }).afterClosed().pipe(filter((task) => task)).subscribe(task => {
      // TODO Create task
      console.log(task);
    });
  }


Can you please cross check and delete all fields from Inspect Elemement from the browser except the title field and action buttons, and check if you are still facing the same  issue?

@JigneshPanchal This issue still occurs even after I removed mat-dialog-content. I noticed that mat-dialog-actions has a padding of 8px. mat-dialog-title and mat-dialog-content have a side padding of 24px. But the padding was definitely not put in place by me.

Okay, but this kind of issue may be resolved by viewing the live site. Because there are many default CSS, this may have an effect.

@JigneshPanchal it seems it is a known bug/error? https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26082

Thanks for drawing attention, but in your case, you can try adding custom CSS.
Change values based on your needs.
`.mat-dialog-container .mat-dialog-actions {
padding: 8px 24px;
}
.mat-dialog-container .mat-dialog-content {
padding-bottom: 25px;
}`
